# Tools to make good clean code in IOS with XCode

Tags: ios

Coming from a C# background with Resharper and all the cool toys, I'm finding my XCode code becomes untidy really quickly. I'm looking for xcode replacements for the following tidy up functions I'm used to using:

- Auto indent
- Auto () {} balancing or arrangement
- Sorting methods in a class (alphabetically)
- Commenting methods so that the comments show up in intellisense
- Auto comment methods (like GhostDoc) in c# land
- Enforcement/Suggestion of naming conventions for methods and variables

If you guys have any other "clean code" tools, please feel free to include.

Comment: See http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/ for comment conventions so comments automatically show up while writing code. Press command-2 to see symbol navigator and have methods listed alphabetically.

Comment: thank you these will help, will add them to the edit part

Comment: By the way, I'm not familiar with GhostDoc, but I've generated documentation from my Objective-C classes using [AppleDoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) and from Swift using [Jazzy](https://github.com/realm/jazzy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the answer is:

- Auto-Indent:

> Option 1: Go to "Edit - Reindent" code for indenting code
>
> Option 2: Install Alcatraz: http://alcatraz.io/ -- then install a plugin to do this. The one I'm currently using is called BBUncrustifyPlugin

- Auto () {} balancing or arrangement
- Sorting methods in a class (alphabetically)

> Press command-2 to see symbol navigator and have methods listed alphabetically (displays methods, not actually sorting the code)

- Commenting methods so that the comments show up in intellisense

> See nshipster.com/swift-documentation for comment conventions so comments automatically show up

- Auto comment methods (like GhostDoc) in c# land

> I've generated documentation from my Objective-C classes using AppleDoc and from Swift using Jazzy (thanks Rob)

- Enforcement/Suggestion of naming conventions for methods and variables

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [AppCode](http://jetbrains.com/appcode) which is made by Jet Brains (same company that makes resharper)